# Search Bar doesn't show the result

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

[image]I'm practicing on UISearch bar. It's supposed to show what it scopes, however I doesn't work. I connected search bar view controller to the original view controller.
I checked the console (I put the NSLog to see if the NSPredicate works property), and it says the result, but not on the screen.
Any advice please.
Thanks:)

#import "ViewController.h"
    #import "detailViewController.h" // I realized it's not good practice. The first letter shold be the upper case

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSMutableArray *_recipes;
    NSString *_recipeName;
    NSArray *_searchResults;
}
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    _recipes = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Egg Benedict",@"Mushroom Risotto",@"Full Breakfast", @"Hamburger",@"Ham and Egg Sandwich", @"Cream Brelee",@"White Chocolate Donut",@"Starbucks Coffee",@"Vegetable Curry", @"Instant Noodle With Egg",@"Noodle with BBQ Pork", @"Japanese Noodle with Pork",@"Green Tea", @"Thai shripm Cake", @"Angry Birds Cake",@"Ham and Cheese Panini",nil];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

# pragma mark Dlegate method

// Data source protocol

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableview numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [_searchResults count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [_recipes count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"RecipeCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }


    if(self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = _searchResults[indexPath.row];
        }
        else
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = _recipes[indexPath.row];
        }


    return cell;

}

// Delegate Protocol


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"row %i and section %i",indexPath.row,indexPath.section);
    _recipeName = _recipes[indexPath.row];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CellSelectionSegue" sender:self];


}

# pragma mark Segue method

-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"segue");

    detailViewController *detailVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    detailVC.string = _recipeName;
    NSLog(@"%@",_recipeName);


}

# pragma mark Searchbar datasource

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    _searchResults = (NSArray *)[_recipes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

    NSLog(@"%@",_searchResults);
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles]
                                      objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar
                                                     selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: try to NSLog the `_searResults` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method

Comment: @GoGreen: It says null.

Comment: can you check whether `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called again after search delegates are called ? I think the problem is that the `tableView` is not reloading.

Comment: what is the result of NSLog statement in filterContentForSearchText method?

Comment: does anything change if you swap `if(self.tableView ==` for `if(tableView ==`?

Comment: @CoGreen: Yeah I made some mistake for the last comment. but now I can  see the list (_searchResults) works in the console, when I type character in the search box. So I guess cellForRowAtIndexPath: works every time I type. I guess "self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView " doesn't work somehow.

Comment: avoid `self.tableView`. Instead, just use `if ( tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView )`. Try if this works.

Comment: @GoGreen Thank you so much ! Everything is perfect! oh and could you fill me in why it works instead of using self.tableView, please. I'm new here.

Comment: @barrett I didn't see your comment above. The answer you gave is right and is indeed the reason why it didn't work.

Comment: @Toshi as mentioned by [barrett](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2484699/barrett) the searchDisplayController actually creates a new tableview on top of your existing tableView. When you use `self.tableView` it always refers to your original `tableView` which is shown initially. The `tableView` in the method `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` actually returns the `tableView` which is referred to in the current context.

Comment: i.e. when you use search, `tableView` actually refers to your `searchDisplayController`'s `tableView`. I hope this clears it.

Comment: @GoGreen I really appreciate your help!! so I used self.tableView at  [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier]; line inside of the method - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, but should i use "tableView" instead? I tried both and both of them work. Which is the better practice?

Comment: OH I also heard "self.tableView because the delegate protocole gives you the table." but is that true? I'm little confused at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the delegates for the `SearchDisplayController`?

```
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
self.searchDisplayController.delegate = self;
```

Edit:

I'll edit my comment into here. I believe the references for

```
if (self.tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
```

should be

```
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
```

The reason is `self.tableView` will never be the `SearchDisplayController` because when initiating the search it actually creates a new `UITableViewController` on top of the original.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more delegate method in `search`. Try adding that to your project.
Here is the code:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text 
                               scope:[[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
    return YES;
}
```